# how can send message to my android app from web service

Tags: android, web-services

I have web service Java(Netbeans), MySql and 2 android application.
I need when database is updated send any message (notification) to application who can help me.

Who can help me or show me some tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You need [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). This is probably the most easy out of the box solution for notifications.

Following keywords can help you further. To notify your web service from the database you could use [Query notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx) or just poll your database.
If GCM is not suitable for you, you could implement a technique called long-polling.